# Sum and show in datagridview database value

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, group-by, sum

I want to sum and show value in `datagridview` using Group By

```
string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Restaurant.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
string query = "SELECT Column2,SUM(Column1),Receipt No,Date From Total Group By[Column2]";
//SELECT Column2 FROM Total GROUP BY [Column2]
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        if (ds != null)
        {
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

when this form load it's close automatically nothing shows anything in datagrdview

Comment: try to open the connection before calling Fill, also your query is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st fix your query:

```
string query = "SELECT Column2,SUM(Column1),[Receipt No],Date From Total Group By [Column2],[Receipt No],Date";
```

and 2nd open connection:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                { 
                  conn.Open();
                   ...
```

**EDIT:**
your 2nd query should be:

```
"SELECT Column3 As [Table No],SUM(Column1) As Price,[Receipt No],Date From Total Where [Receipt No] = '" + textBox1.Text + "' Group By [Column3],[Receipt No],[Date]";
```

Comment: when i write after column2 As Table No it's again close automatically and not showing anything

Comment: us brackets: as [Table No]

Comment: hmmm good its working one more thing i wanna ask you it's necessary to write conn.open bcz it's already working without it

Comment: sir please help me i am facing issue with this query

Comment: string query = "SELECT Column3 As [Table No],SUM(Column1) As Price,[Receipt No],Date From Total Group By [Column3],[Receipt No],[Date] Where [Receipt No] = " + textBox1.Text + "";

Comment: sorry i didn't get you please explain me

Comment: which quote i need to add before textbox?

Comment: glad to help, please consider up voting my answer

Comment: Sir i want  your help can you please tell me how to change forecolor of selected listbox items i don't want to change listbox fore color i just want to change selected listbox item

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < lbProductsToBuy.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        lbProductsToBuy.SetSelected(i,true);
                    }
                    printreceiptToken1();
                    dataGridView67.Rows.Clear();

Comment: i am using this query to select listbox items and i want to change of forecolor of this selected items of listbox

Comment: sir this query is not working now string query = "SELECT Column2,SUM(Column1),[Receipt No],Date From Total Group By [Column2],[Receipt No],Date"; how can i solve this it;s now showing me group by

Answer (score 0):

Please check conn.Open(); seems missing.

```
 using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
 { 
     conn.Open();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     if (ds != null)
     {
          adapter.Fill(ds);

          dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     ......
```

Hope this helps!